# Windows 7: disable all restarts by microsoft and 3rd party updates

Tags: windows-7, reboot

Is there a way of globally preventing automatic restarts from all updates, e.g. Microsoft updates, Flash, Adobe PDF, AVG, and any others that decide to be a nuisance? I need my computer to be on throughout the night without being interrupted.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is no way of globally preventing it, unfortunately for your problem.

But there is a way, to turn off the automatic restarts after windows update (at least).

Go to **Run** and type in: **gpedit.msc**

Now go to: Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Update > **No auto-restart with logged on users scheduled automatic updates installation**

And maybe you could also disable the "sleep"-mode, this is also a thing that is a nuisance (in my eyes).

```
Go to Start->Control Panel->Power Options

Select **Change when the computer sleeps**

Choose **Never** and Save changes
```

Comment: For future readers, `gpedit.msc` is only available on Windows 7 Professional and Ultimate Edtitions. It is not available on Home Premium.